# is it possible to integrate intel sources like proofpoint, croud strike, Mandiant etc in IBM Cloud native?

Tags: ibm-cloud

We have actively worked on various integrations within IBM QRadar and we have taken note of the IBM roadmap emphasizing IBM Cloud Native solutions. To prepare for this shift, we've begun exploring IBM Cloud documentation and have found this Slack channel to be a valuable resource. As newcomers to IBM Cloud, we've formulated some questions after navigating through multiple pages and documents. Your assistance with any of these queries would be highly appreciated.

- Are the IBM Cloud and IBM Cloud Native the same thing?
- What are the Key features provided by the IBM Cloud? Such as in QRadar we have log activity to monitor collected events, DSM to parse and map the events, Rules-Offences, Reference Sets to store data, Custom Dashboards, etc.
- What is the difference between the IBM QRadar and IBM Cloud?
- From the development perspective how we can build new integration on the IBM Cloud and deliver to the customer?
- Also, from the development perspective how we can migrate the existing QRadar integration to the IBM Cloud?

I had go through the 3 features log analysis,event stream and mobitoring.
My basic need to identify that is it possible to integrate intel sources like proofpoint, croud strike, Mandiant etc in IBM Cloud native?
Also need to know that features like DMS and Logactivities are provided by IBM Cloud native?